# How to input constraints on parameters?

Tags: particle-swarm

I am currently doing a materials prediction project using PSO and I was wondering if anyone can provide any expertise. I utilize PSO as my method of operation but I am trying to handle a constraint

For eg: I have 17 input parameters for the algorithm to take references from and make predictions. However, these 17 elements should not exceed 100%. May I know how do I input the constraints?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHWcH.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Apply the constraint before the objective function is updated but after the particle position has been updated. Let say after velocity/location update, your particle is now located at [5,5] while your constraint (Ub) is [4,3]. Simply modify your particle location to [4,3]. Other people use more exotic method such as 'bouncing', like when hitting a wall with a ball. E.g., original particle location is [3,3] with velc of [4,2] (same Ub). Due to the constraint and bouncing, the particle is now at [0,1] (3+((4-3)-3)).

Code example for the former method

```
% Fixing the Boundary
bindex_up = x(pop_iter,:) > ub;
bindex_down = x(pop_iter,:) < lb;

x(pop_iter,bindex_up)=ub(bindex_up);
x(pop_iter,bindex_down)=lb(bindex_down);
```

2. Do not change the particle position, but if the particle location is outside the Ub or Lb, apply a penalty to the fitness/obj function.

Nature Inspired Metaheuristic has more details on this subject (Constrain handling) https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/1628847